# In WIX, Access data of a Form collection using velo code

Tags: forms, collections, velo

I created a website form, and gave it a name 'NewIntakeForm'.  Then I can see a new Wix App collection with the same name have been created under the Form Section.

I am wondering how to access the data of this "NewIntakeForm" collection using velo code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy9HP.png)

I tried  the following but not working at all.

wixData.query("Forms/NewIntakeForm").find();

Also I can't find the collection ID of a Wix App collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet found an answer, or for those who come here looking for the answer, here you go...

On the left panel of the editor open the "Databases" icon.  This will expand a panel with all the collections (but in this view Wix calls them Databases).  Scroll down until you find the "Forms", and expand that, if it isn't already expanded.

Now, locate the forms collection you want to query, select it, you will see a "Copy collection id".  This will copy, into the clipboard, the ID Wix magically assigned to the collection.